# Show custom error page for 404.7. UseStatusCodePages() does not work

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-2.0

I would like to display custom pages for errors in my ASP Core 2.0 MVC app. But I am only able to achieve this for some error types.

By default, a 404 error looks like this:

[image: 404 error]

I believe the correct way to catch and customize errors such as 404 (not found) in an ASP Core 2.0 app is to use app.UseStatusCodePages() middleware in Configure() in Startup.cs. I have done this, or more specifically I have used app.UseStatusCodePagesWithReExecute() since I wanted to create my own error pages.

```
app.UseStatusCodePagesWithReExecute("/Error/Index", "?statusCode={0}");
```

Now, when I browse to a resource that doesn't exist, I see my custom error message, since the code is successfully intercepting the 404 error:

[image: Customized 404 error]

**Ok, so that seems to be working.**

However I then tried navigating to https://localhost:44300/Startup.cs

This gives me a 404.7 error, presumably because a user should never be allowed to navigate to this file. More importantly though, **I do not see my custom error page this time**. Instead I see a page that looks like it has been generated by the server.

[image: 404.7 error]

I have a few questions related to this:

1. Why is this happening? When I have used app.UseStatusCodePages(), why is this 404.7 error not being captured by the middleware the same way a 404 error is?
2. Where does this error get generated? I get the feeling that this is being generated by IIS server settings, since the error itself says I should verify settings in applicationhost.config or web.config.

But (i) there is no web.config in an ASP Core 2.0 app, so I don't see where these settings could have come from, and (ii) I believe ASP Core 2.0 uses Kestral, and not IIS, and I don't see any Kestral settings in my app either.

3. What can I do to replace this error page with my own customized error page, just as I did with the 404 errors?

Comment: It's probably the fact it's a `*.cs` extension, I assume `anything.cs` will give you the same message.

Comment: @DavidG: Agreed, code files are probably blocked by default, but my question is on how to customize the error that is displayed when this happens. (I'm also not sure where the setting to block access to such files has been placed. Prior to ASP Core, one would see this setting inserted by default in web.config, but now I don't see a web.config at all).

Comment: I can't reproduce this on a mac. The error page looks like an IIS error page. Could you use `dotnet run` on the command line and see if this still happens?

Comment: Show us the logic inside your error controller index method. Might as well show the Configure section from Startup.cs

Comment: @gldraphael - I was unable to use dotnet run to test this. Unfortunately my code is set up to automatically redirect to https, and for whatever reason the https urls do not appear to work when the app is run using "dotnet run". Every page gives an error. (Best guess - Maybe dotnet run uses kestral, and kestral does not autogenerate an ssl certificate the way IIS does, so nothing will work without further configuration).

Comment: @gldraphael - I disabled all the SSL related stuff in my project and ran it using "dotnet run". As you suspected, that particular error does not happen anymore, and I see my own custom error page. So you are correct - the error is generated by IIS. Since the app will eventually be hosted on Azure, which means it will be running on IIS, how can I prevent IIS from displaying its own error? Should I create a web.config, or is there some other settings file in ASP Core 2.0 that should be used?

Comment: @Gary yes you'll need a `web.config` file. Mark G's comment below answers shows how to disable it.

Comment: Can you share where you put your Error file ? I tried to put in in Views but can't get it to work. I even tried adding an ErrorController but that did not work as well

Comment: @AlexandreG I created an ErrorController controller with an Index() action, and a corresponding view (i.e., in Views folder I have created an Error folder, and within it an Index.cshtml file). This should get triggered as long as RequestFiltering doesn't kick in, so navigate to a url like https://localhost:44300/abc which won't trigger it. [For RequestFiltering, see the selected answer by Nish26, as well as my discussion with him below it. You might need to run on Kestrel in order for your errors to actually reach the ASP Core and be processed by  app.UseStatusCodePagesWithReExecute()].

Comment: Thanks @Gary ! Can I ask what you put as arguments of the Index action to know that the error is actually a 404 ? Is there a variable to switch on ?

Comment: @AlexandreG In Startup.cs, my statement is -  `app.UseStatusCodePagesWithReExecute("/Error/Index", "?statusCode={0}")`  The status code gets put in the place of the {0} by the pipeline. As you can see, I have named the parameter statusCode. So my Index() action in ErrorController also needs to have a parameter named statusCode if I want to read it. It looks like this - `public IActionResult Index(int? statusCode = null) { .... }`

Comment: That was the piece I was missing, thanks !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[RequestFiltering](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/configuration/system.webserver/security/requestfiltering/) is a security feature of IIS which is what is blocking your requests and displaying that message. When you try to debug asp.net core apps, kestrel is used automatically using IIS. If you want to bypass IIS and use kestrel directly as a standalone server, you can do so in visual studio by clicking the down arrow button [image] next to IIS Express and selecting the name of project in drop down. If you debug now, it will open a console window which is kestrel server running as standalone application.

Kestrel is not a fully featured web server and in a production environment you would typically run it along with some other server such as IIS or Nginx which will act as a reverse proxy server.

Comment: Running directly using kestrel should bypass RequestFiltering feature of IIS and should allow your app.UseStatusCodePagesWithReExecute() handler to do its job.

Comment: I was unable to successfully test that out on kestral. I tried to bypass Kestral using the method you suggested. I suspect it did not work because I have configured my app to run on Https only, and to run on Kestral I will need to do some additional configuration and provide a certificate. I'll take your word for it though, since what you say makes sense, and I too suspected this was RequestFiltering (it was one of the things mentioned in the error message).

Comment: That being said, I plan to run on IIS; the app will be hosted as an Azure web site, which I believe automatically runs IIS (or maybe it runs kestral on IIS). So I need a way to override these IIS settings, and allow the errors to reach my app so it can display a custom error page. How can I achieve this? Should I create a web.config and add it to the project?

Comment: Ok, so I disabled all the SSL related stuff (redirect to https, https-only attributes, https cookies etc) in my project and ran it on Kestral. This time it ran just fine. You are correct - this bypassed IIS, and now the error displayed is my own custom error message. So the request is now successfully reaching the app rather than being intercepted by IIS. When I host this on Azure, it believe it will run on IIS. How do I prevent IIS from displaying its own error and allowing mine to be displayed instead?

Comment: @Gary [How to disable Request Filtering for a specific website on IIS](https://serverfault.com/questions/359635/how-to-disable-request-filtering-for-a-specific-website-on-iis-7-5).

Comment: Thanks, RequestFiltering was responsible for this. Specifically the fact that I was navigating to a .cs file (Startup.cs) was causing the 404.7 response from IIS, since by default it is set to block that file extension.